# How render tiptap/ProseMirror editor, as diagram?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tiptap

## **Hello**, I hope this message finds you well.

My team is currently working on a text editor that can represent a default WYSIWYG editor as a flow chart diagram. We are using Tiptap to create the WYSIWYG editor.
We are wondering what the best practice is for rendering a ProseMirror model as a diagram? We appreciate any insights you may have on this matter.

I tried to get the JSON of the editor state and parse it into JSON, which we then pass to React Flow. However, I don't like this solution at all.

Comment: Have you found any other solution?